# Centre of mass vector of a leaning ladder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

A ladder (uniform rod) of length 2L and mass M resting against a wall. $\theta$ is the angle between the ladder and the y axis.

I know that the COM vector is trivial by inspection but I'm having a lot of trouble computing it.

The COM is : $$\vec{R} = \frac{1}{M}\int\vec{r}dm$$

But the mass element for the ladder is : $$ dm = \mu dl = \frac{M}{2L}dl$$

And this line element is : $$dl = rd\phi$$ where $\phi$ is this angle between the ladder and the x axis.

Then $$\vec{R} = \frac{1}{2L}\int r^2 d\phi$$ in the radial r hat direction.

I'm going round in circles trying to get this into an integrable form with the correct bounds, given that $l$ goes from $0$ to 2L.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Break this into the $x$ direction and the $y$ direction to get the $x$ and the $y$ coordinates of the center of mass.  You actually needn't do any explicit integrals:  the center of mass (of the uniform bar) is halfway between the horizontal positions of its tips, and halfway between the vertical positions of its tips.  (See why?)

Comment: Thanks, I do see that. However, I'm trying to practice these computations since I struggle with them and am very frustrated that I cant seem to derive the trivial result

Comment: Your statement $dl=rd\phi$ is wrong.  That is the line element around the circumference of a circle.  Really all you want to do here is parametrize the position by length, $\vec{r}(l) = (l\sin(\theta),l\cos(\theta))^T$, and then integrate from $l=0$ to $l=2L$.

Answer (score 1):

$$CM_x = \frac{1}{M} \int\limits_{x=0}^{L \sin \theta} x\ dm$$

Note that $\frac{dx}{dl} = \sin \theta$

So:

$$CM_x= \int\limits_{x=0}^{L \sin \theta} x \frac{1}{L} \frac{1}{\sin \theta}\ dx$$

$$= \frac{1}{L \sin \theta} \frac{(L \sin \theta)^2}{2} = \frac{L \sin \theta}{2}$$

and likewise for the vertical component.